# How to group array by user_id in Laravel 8

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I create the CRUD App. In this App, the user can add a contact, and include their birthday in that contact.

I have two tables in PHP MySQL: students and users. When their contact at the students' table has a birthday, the user will receive an email.

To test the email work, I'm using MailHog. It's was work.

I test that there are two users with a birthday in that contact.
One user has a notification email. Another one has two notification emails because that contact has two data that are two birthdays.

The problem is, that I want to send one notification to every user. So if one user has many contacts on that birthday, it will give the user one email notification, instead of many emails.

this is the notification in MailHog:

[image]

user john has two notifications, instead of one.

this is my code:

```
 public function handle()
{
    
    info('mail first');
    sleep(1);
    info('mail second');
    $student = Student::whereMonth('birth', date('m-d'))
                        ->whereDay('birth', date('d') )
                        
                        ->get();

    foreach ($student as $mystudent) {

    $user = User::find($mystudent->user_id);


    Mail::to($user)->send(new WelcomeMail($mystudent));

    }

    // dd($userid);


    echo "check email";

   
}
```

this code in class WelcomeMail

```
public function __construct($students)
{
    $this->data = $students;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{

    

    return $this->view('emails.welcome')->with('students', $this->data);
}
```

this is in view:

```
    {{ $students}}
```

I do this modiv in mail command:

```
 $userid = [];                  
    foreach ($student as $mystudent) {

    $user = User::find($mystudent->user_id);
    array_push($userid, $user);


    Mail::to($user)->send(new WelcomeMail($mystudent));

    }
```

At this point, it's still given me the result that the user has many emails for each contact.

hopefully, you help me train logic to solve this one.

+

this the database looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start your query from the user, so you're sure that every user is present only once.

I'm assuming you have `students()` relation present on the `User::class` model

```
public function handle()
{
    $users = User::wherehas('students', function($studentQuery) {
        $studentQuery
            ->whereMonth('birth', date('m-d'))
            ->whereDay('birth', date('d'));
    })
        ->with('students', function($studentQuery) {
            $studentQuery
                ->whereMonth('birth', date('m-d'))
                ->whereDay('birth', date('d'));
        })
        ->get();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        Mail::to($user)->send(new WelcomeMail($user->students));
    }

    echo "check email";
}
```

Comment: I just apply that code, it has given me just two emails, for one user and another, but in the user that has two contacts, just give first contact, instead of all contact Sir. And in the email, not contain, the contact that birthday, it has given the email with the first created

Comment: I just edited it to view the database that in PHP MySQL, in database api4, there were many tables including the students and users dude.

Comment: I did, it got, the email that one user has one notif, but the contact that does not has birthday included in that email dude

Comment: That's cool, you answer just like what my senior suggested. I still struggle with logic, like how to use looping properly and where I will do looping. Maybe you can recommend my resource so that I can learn logic, Sir.

Comment: that's something, thanks for your advice, I need more advice from others who experts in programming, tank's dude

Answer (score 0):

```php
$student = Student::whereMonth('birth', date('m-d'))
    ->whereDay('birth', date('d'))
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I was doing that, by following this documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#grouping

it's using: 

->groupBy

it's got an error dude